# simple login node.js+mongoDB Cannot POST/ login

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mongodb

I have some problems to get a login for my webpage.

I have a user in my DB with email: peru@hotmail.com and pass 123.

the problem is that when I make the POST method it returns me the next error:

```
*Cannot POST /login*
```

this is my app.js:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var express = require('express');
var app=express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/myDB");
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
var userSchema = {
    email:String,
    pass:String
};

var Usuario = mongoose.model("Usuario",userSchema);
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.get("/",function(solicitud,respuesta){
    respuesta.sendFile('.../prueba.html');
});

app.post("/login",function(require,respuesta){
    var email = require.body.email;
    var pass = require.body.pass;
    console.log("post received: %s %s", email, pass);
    User.findOne({email: email, pass: pass}, function(err,user){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }    
        respuesta.sendFile('.../work.html');
    });
}); 
app.listen(3000);
```

and now this is my prueba.html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <!--div class="col-md-5 center-block no float top-pace text-left"-->
    <form method="post" action="/login" >
        <input type="text" name="email">
        <input type="text"  name="pass" >
        <button type="submit" >login </button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't know what the problem is but I see some configurations missing:

First:

Before this line:
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/myDB");

Write this:
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
Second:

Transform this:
var userSchema = {
    email:String,
    pass:String
};

Into this:
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    email:String,
    pass:String
});
Let me know if you're still getting the same error.

Comment: where you defined `User`?

Comment: Instead of User wanted to put Usuario @Arpit

Comment: @DuarteMendes the problem still appearing :(

Comment: I´ve solved the problem guys, thank you a lot for your support.

Comment: I didn´t type the get function of the login: app.get("/login")....

Answer (score 0):

You created [model](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html) as `Usuario` and using `User` in your `POST` request, try changing it to `Usuario`, as follows:

```
app.post("/login",function(require,respuesta){
    var email = require.body.email;
    var pass = require.body.pass;
    console.log("post received: %s %s", email, pass);
    Usuario.findOne({email: email, pass: pass}, function(err,user){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }    
        respuesta.sendFile('.../work.html');
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried your option but the problem keeps there... :(